# Headers on VMWare vCenter API Calls

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cors, vmware, next.js

I am working on an internal web app to help manage infrastructure elements at our office. We currently one run host with vSphere & vCenter Server installed, with other hosts cycling in and out as needed. The setup is pretty simple to be honest, but definitely more complicated than some of the team needs to deal with on a daily basis. To make it easier, I have a React app built that our team is able to login to and provision servers, get IP addresses, power on / off vms, etc...

Postman works perfectly well using the samples from the SDK kit, but when moving it into the web app and Chrome, I get the standard CORS issues, the main one being a missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. Actual error below but I doubt anyone will need it.

My question is if it is possible to even edit the headers of the VMWare vCenter Appliance to fix this issue. I have narrowed the area that the headers may originate, down to a reverse proxy service called rhttpproxy, or httpd, but can't get much farther than that without a lot of digging through python or conf files.

Hopefully someone has an answer for this, even if it is just that it is impossible. Thanks in advance!

```
Failed to load https://{{vc}}/rest/com/vmware/cis/session: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/496311) help

Comment: Well it sheds some light on how vCO is having the same issue, but the vCSA instance is Linux based, so not exactly the same. I actually don't see tomcat on the vm at all. It looks like httpd (apache) is serving as the main webserver. I found where httpd is loading mod_headers, so going to try working with that to make it work. I have a feeling though the rhttpproxy is the place where this is going to need to be edited though as it is the listener at 80 & 443.